# Elasticsearch 2.4.3 having issue with .docx file during creating document index

Tags: c#, asp.net, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-plugin

Thanks in advance

I am new in elasticsearch and using elasticsearch 2.4.3. When I am indexing documents then .doc, pdf,txt,xls is working fine but when I tried with .docx file then it is creating issue.

Below are response which I am getting, It is showing successful but in Response section, we are getting **created : false**

```
Successful low level call on PUT: /ilemsdocuments/indexeddocument/F%3A%5CIndexTestSamples%5CIndexTestSamples%5CBaconNarrative.docx?pretty=true
# Audit trail of this API call:
 - [1] HealthyResponse: Node: http://localhost:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.1688474


         # Request:
        {
        "activityNumber": "2016-001390",
        "activityOccurrenceDate": "2016-03-09T00:00:00",
        "activityPrepDate": "2016-01-26T00:00:00",
        "activityReportDate": "2016-01-08T00:00:00",
        "author": "Bard Laabs",
        "category": "Interviews",
        "dataOwnerDatabase": "main",
        "dataOwnerDisk": "main",
        "databaseLastUpdate": "2016-03-28T00:00:00",
        "documentEntityId":   "F:\\IndexTestSamples\\IndexTestSamples\\BaconNarrative.docx",
      "file": {
        "_content": "-- Remove the actual content as its size is big",
        "_indexed_chars": -1
      },
      "fileExtension": "docx",
      "fileFullName": "F:\\IndexTestSamples\\IndexTestSamples\\BaconNarrative.docx",
      "indexedFileInfo": {
        "creationTime": "2016-09-09T12:50:32+05:30",
        "fullName": "F:\\IndexTestSamples\\IndexTestSamples\\BaconNarrative.docx",
        "lastIndexTime": "2017-01-03T11:55:20.6993801+05:30",
        "lastWriteTime": "2017-01-03T11:52:18.1251173+05:30",
        "length": 14479
      },
      "fileLastUpdate": "2017-01-03T11:52:18.1251173+05:30",
      "fileName": "BaconNarrative.docx",
      "indexDate": "2017-01-03T11:55:20.6993801+05:30",
      "indexSource": "IndexingAgent.FileWatcher",
      "indexedPath": "F:\\IndexTestSamples\\IndexTestSamples",
      "isLocked": false,
      "isNarrative": false,
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
      "title": "My Document: 2017-01-03T11:55:22.3480831+05:30",
      "uploadedBy": "testuser"
    }



     # Response:
        {
        "_index" : "ilemsdocuments",
        "_type" : "indexeddocument",
        "_id" : "F:\\IndexTestSamples\\IndexTestSamples\\BaconNarrative.docx",
        "_version" : 3,
        "_shards" : {
          "total" : 2,
          "successful" : 1,
          "failed" : 0
         },
        "created" : false
        }
```

Please help me, if someone face this issue.

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail to be able to answer your question - Are you using the mapper-attachment plugin (I assume so)? What does the mapping of `indexeddocument` type in `ilemsdocuments` look like? What does the docx in question look like? Can you provide a small reproducible example? What version of NEST are you using?

Comment: thanks! yaa you are right, we are using the mapper-attachment plugin in this we are using the elastic search 2.4.3. thats just create the problem while indexing the document for the second time after deleting the indexed document with the extension .docx file rest extension files are created successfully. It gaves the error that we have shown above.yes of course the NEST version is 2.0.0